# Binding A Select2-Bootstrap Plugin to a Dynamically Created Select Element

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2, event-delegation

When using Select2-Bootstrap I register the event handler with the recommended declaration

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.ctaskSelector').select2({
     theme: "classic"
  })
})
```

However if you dynamically add a `Select` element to the `ctaskSelector` class then the `Select` element is not bound to the new entity and the select box behaves as a default select element:

I have tried using Event Delegation which captures the events okay but the Select2 behaviour and features are not available.  Does anyone have some pointers as to how I can resolve this?

Comment: You simply need to execute this line of code *after* you append the element. Event delegation isn't relevant to this problem

Comment: Damn.   I thought that was the solution but I was attempting to do it in a  more complicated way.  Many thanks!